# Return integer and fractional part of a decimal number using QGIS 3.10 expressions

Tags: qgis, expression, integer

I would like to extract a part of a decimal number. In other words, I would like to use 'substr' for decimal numbers to extract integer and fractional part. I could use substr but it does give a different result for a whole number.

Comment: `<integer>.<fraction> % 1 = 0.<fraction>`; use `modulo 1` to get the fractional part

Answer (score 1):

Use a case statement and floor() or ceil()  in the QGIS field calculator to get the factional or interger portions of you data.  For example, to get the integer portion use

```
CASE
    WHEN "yournumber" > 0 THEN  floor( "yournumber")
    WHEN "yournumber"< 0 THEN  ceil( "yournumber")
END
```

and for the decimal portion use

```
CASE
    WHEN "yournumber" > 0 THEN  "yournumber - floor( "yournumber")
    WHEN "yournumber"< 0 THEN  "yournumber - ceil( "yournumber")
END
```

And depending on whether you want the negative values or not in the final calculation you can multiply by -1 accordingly.

Comment: I have both positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i use to get the part on the left or the right  of the decimal dot

```
 left(   "decimal number" , strpos(  "decimal number" ,'.')-1)
```

For example, the decimal number is 123.789

*strpos(* will get the position of the dot (=4)

*left(* will return the numbers starting from the left until the position is reached (123.) so the dot will be included, that's why I added *-1*

```
right( "decimal number", length("decimal number") - strpos( "decimal number",'.'))
```

This works to get the decimal part only